# Send data via USB using STX ETC LRC framing (SerialPort object)

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a simple Forms app to send data over a USB port to a listening terminal device.  I have been told that I need to send the data using STX ETX LRC framing but I have no idea what that means.  I am a software tester for our company and not familiar with data transmissions via usb.  Is there anyone who can help me with this?  This is my current forms code:

```
private void sendRequestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        _serialPort = new SerialPort
        {
            PortName = portsDropdown.Text,
            BaudRate = 19200,//connectionTypeDropdown.Text.Equals(Usb) ? 115200 : 19200,
            DataBits = 8,
            Parity = Parity.None,
            StopBits = StopBits.One,
        };

        _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        _serialPort.Open();

        _serialPort.Write(requestTextbox.Text);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, @"Caught Exception:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        _serialPort.Close();
    }
}

private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;
    _response = serialPort.ReadExisting();
    Debug.Print(_response);
}
```

Comment: Practice the "I know what you're talking about" look in a mirror.  Then go back to whomever told you this and say "okay, but how is the checksum calculated?"  There is more than one way, demand good documentation.  It is always available.

Comment: "I have been told that I need to send the data using..." - why can't you ask that person for more details? Maybe for some links to documentation what "STX ETX LRC framing" is. Then look at github, I bet there is already some library available for this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I used for connecting through the serial port in C#.  This is in WPF so you'll have to make some adjustments.

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace SerialTest
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
    int intBaud = 0;
    string strComport = "";
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        cbCom.ItemsSource = ports;
    }
    private void StartUp()
    {
        int intbaud;
        if (int.TryParse(cbBaud.SelectionBoxItem.ToString(), out intbaud))
        {
            intBaud = intbaud;
           strComport = cbCom.SelectedItem.ToString();

            SerialStart();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid Baudrate");
        }
    }
    private void SerialStart()
    {
        try
        {
            port.BaudRate = int.Parse(cbBaud.SelectionBoxItem.ToString());
            port.DataBits = 8;
            port.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), "One");
            port.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), "None");
            port.PortName = cbCom.SelectedItem.ToString();
            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialReceive);
            port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            if (port.IsOpen) port.Close();
            port.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtTerm.AppendText(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    public enum LogMsgType { Incoming, Outgoing, Normal, Warning, Error };
    private void Log(LogMsgType msgtype, string msg)
    {
        try
        {
            txtTerm.Dispatcher.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
            {
                txtTerm.AppendText(msg);
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
    }
    private void SerialReceive(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!port.IsOpen) return;
        string data = port.ReadExisting();
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            txtTerm.AppendText(data);
            txtTerm.ScrollToEnd();
        });
    }

    private void txtInput_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Return && port.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                port.WriteLine(txtInput.Text + "\r\n");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    txtTerm.AppendText(ex.ToString()); ;
                });
            }
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                txtTerm.AppendText(txtInput.Text + "\n");
                txtInput.Text = "";
            });
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Edit**
Looks like for STX and ETC you have to also convert the characters to bytes
https://www.codeproject.com/questions/1107562/sending-ascii-control-stx-and-etx-in-csharp